# Understanding the volume of $k$-parallelpiped in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, lebesgue-measure, volume, convex-geometry

This question is related to [Computing the volume of a fundamental domain of a lattice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234675/computing-the-volume-of-a-fundamental-domain-of-a-lattice). I have been trying to understand similar concepts as
in this question, but still unclear about couple points.

Let $v_1, ..., v_k$ be linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $k < n$.
Let $\sigma$ be the parallelpiped formed by these $k$ vectors inside $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Then as described in one of the answers
$$
vol(\sigma)=\sqrt{\mid \det A A^T\mid}
$$
with matrix $A = [v_1 ... v_k]$.

Question 1. What does the volume mean precisely in this context? It makes sense to me when $k = n$, it is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n,$ but was not sure when $k < n$. Any clarification is appreciated!

Question 2. I was wondering if someone could explain how the two answers in [Computing the volume of a fundamental domain of a lattice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234675/computing-the-volume-of-a-fundamental-domain-of-a-lattice) are the same?

Comment: Lebesgue measure on the spanned subspace.

Comment: What does that mean exactly? thank you

Comment: If you have $2$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ it would give you the area of the spanned parallelogram.

Comment: I think you've written down $A^T$ instead of $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just going to answer the first question and say why the formula  should be clear.

Question 1:

Let's say you have a $k$-dimensional real vector space $V$. In order to define a Lebesgue measure on $V$, it's enough to select a basis. You transport Lebesgue measure on $R^k$ to $V$ via the coordinate map $V \to R^k$ associated with that basis.

Now if you replace the basis you have with a second one, the measure on $V$ will remain unchanged as long as the transition matrix between the two bases has determinant $\pm 1$. So in order to define a measure on $V$, instead of singling out one basis, it's enough to single out a class of bases which are all related to each other in this way.

Returning now to your problem, let $V$ be the subspace of $R^n$ spanned by $v_1, \dots, v_k$. It so happens that we can distinguish such a class of bases of $V$, namely, all bases which are orthonormal with respect to the standard inner product of $R^n$. Since the transition matrices between these bases are orthogonal, they have determinant $\pm 1$, as required. This defines the measure on $V$.

Proof of the formula:

The first answer given in the link is, I think, not much more helpful than what I wrote above, so I'll just say why the formula in the second answer should be obvious.

I imagine you already agree with the formula $(\det AA^T)^{1/2}$ in the case $k = n$, as this is just $|\det A|$. Clearly,
$AA^T = (<v_i,v_j>)_{i,j}$ (this equality also being valid when $k < n$). Thus when $k = n$, we have an expression for the volume of the parallelepiped in terms of the inner products of the spanning vectors.

But as I explained in answering Question 1, in the case $k < n$ the concept of volume in $V$ depends only on the inner product induced on $V$ by the one on $R^n$. So the very same formula for the volume of the parallelipiped must be valid in the case of $V$.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Could you please explain one thing?  "You transport Lebesgue measure on $R^k$ to $V$ via the coordinate map $V \to R^k$ associated with that basis." How does $\det A A^T$ come out when computing the volume using the Lebesgue measure on $V$?

Comment: Hi, Question 1 was just about showing what Lebesgue measure on $V$ means, not about the formula. Really, it shows how the concept is automatically meaningful as soon as you have a finite-deimensional $R$-vector space and an inner product on it. Then the argument is this: (1) the formula $(\det AA^T)^{1/2}$ and the formula with the inner products of the $v_i$'s  are equivalent.(2) You show that the formula with $AA^T$ is valid for the entire space, hence the formula with inner products is too. (3) Since from Question 1, the whole concept of Lebesgue measure on a space can be determined...

Comment: from the inner product on it, the fact that the formula with inner products is valid on a space spanned by the $v_i$'s proves that it's valid on a subspace. (4) By (1), then , the formula with $AA^T$ is aso valid on the subspace.