# An upperbound for the volume of parallepiped is the product of the lengths?

Tags: linear-algebra, lebesgue-measure, volume, convex-geometry

Let $v_1, ..., v_k$ be linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $k < n$.
Let $\sigma$ be the parallelpiped formed by these $k$ vectors inside $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Then as described in [Understanding the volume of $k$-parallelpiped in $\mathbb{R}^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4230191/understanding-the-volume-of-k-parallelpiped-in-mathbbrn)
$$
vol(\sigma)=\sqrt{\mid \det A^T A \mid}
$$
with matrix $A = [v_1 ... v_k]$.

I've been trying to prove that
$$
vol(\sigma) \leq \prod_{i=1}^k || v_i||_2. 
$$
My strategy was to use induction, but the determinant expression is quite complicated and it had not been helpful. Any suggestion on how I can prove this is appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't the Gram-Schmidt process preserve the parallelipiped volume and shorten the vectors' lengths?

Comment: I think you are right... thanks!